# How/What to return in this case?

Tags: c++, stl, coding-style

**CODE:**

```
vector<DWORD> get_running_proc_list()
{
    DWORD proc_list[1024], size;

    if(!EnumProcesses(proc_list, sizeof(proc_list), &size))
    {
        return 0; // PROBLEM HERE!! 
    }

    vector<DWORD> _procs(proc_list, proc_list + size/sizeof(DWORD));
    return _procs;
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
cannot convert from 'int' to 'const std::vector<_Ty>'
```

What is the best possible way to fix this  error?
**Is there a better way than just returning an empty vector?**

Comment: You can pass `vector<>` as reference parameter to function.

Comment: How many of you read the question before posting your answer? :D

Answer (score 4):

Well, your function returns `vector`, not `DWORD`. Can't you return just an empty vector:

```
return std::vector< DWORD >();
```

or

```
return std::vector< DWORD >( 1, 0 );
```

If you really need the `0`?

---

**EDIT**:

There's another option, if empty vector is not a solution (in case, that it's some kind of valid value and you need to know) - use exception. You can make your own class for exception or use some standard one. So, you can do it like this:

```
if(!EnumProcesses(proc_list, sizeof(proc_list), &size))
{
   throw MyException( "some message, if you want" );
}
```

I'd advice, if you choose this option, to inherit `std::exception`.

Or, you can return pointer to `std::vector` and return `NULL` in this case. But I would **not** recommend this. But it's just my opinion.

Comment: @MachineCharmer, `vector::size()` checked for `0` is also equivalent to checking for `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Throw an exception. That's what they're for. After all, there definitely should be a list of processes that are running.

And definitely do not fail to return by value or something. In this case, the RVO/NRVO is trivially applied. I mean, at worst, you could swaptimize.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *(after reading edited version of question)*

Alternatives:

1. You can make your function to return `void` and pass to it a vector by reference (or by pointer) then fill the vector in function body.
2. You can make your function to return `boost::shared_ptr<vector<DWORD> >` (or some other [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)), construct and fill the vector in function body (of course in dynamic memory), then return it's address or NULL.
3. Throw an exception if above solutions are not suitable.

Comment: +1: But there can be a situation where an empty vector isn't the same as, say, a "null" vector, in which case I'd recommend returning a pointer(a smart pointer, of course) to a vector, and return a null pointer

Comment: @Armen +1 for good comment. In any case returning pointer or reference instead of object is less expensive.

Comment: returning a pointer may be less expensive, but in order to do that you'd have to `new` the vector, which may be more expensive (especially if the compiler can optimise out the copy on return). I'd recommend throwing an exception, rather than trying to encode an exceptional case into a return value.

Comment: -1 Of course you shouldn't return empty vector. `EnumProcesses` just failed!

Comment: @Martinho particularly it depends on what the program should do. But in any case after rereading edited version of the question I decided change the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!EnumProcesses(proc_list, sizeof(proc_list), &size))
{
  vector<DWORD> empty;       
  return empty;  <--- 0 sized vector
}
```

You can return an empty `vector<>`.

As a side note, I would **not recommend to return** `vector` **by value**. Instead pass the `vector<>` as parameter to be assured that unnecessary copies will not happen.

```
void get_running_proc_list(vector<DWORD> &_procs) pass by reference and populate
{
...
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to first write the code so that it optimally expresses your intent (and a function that creates a `blarg` shoudl return a `blarg`, not take one per non-`const` ref), and leave such optimizations until you've measured and found this particular case worth optimizing. (FWIW, I really doubt that, when you mess with processes, returning a `std::vector` of a few dozen integers will make a noticeable difference. And even if - then comes along C++11 with rvalue references and move semantics and renders your "optimization" totally useless, because it skips copying...)

Comment: @sbi, OP had asked `how/what to return` initially. Then edited to `Is there any better way ?`. My answer is for the initial question. Also OP has neither mentioned `c++0x` as scope, nor how big the `vector` would be. In such case, passing a `vector` as a function argument would be a good choice.

Comment: C++11 or not - I'd only do such an optimization after having measured that it's worth to do so. And note that, while I don't like that second part of your answer, _I_ haven't downvoted it, because I like the first part.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
return 0; // PROBLEM HERE!!
```

with

```
return vector<DWORD>(); // NO PROBLEM!!
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a `boost::optional`? It adds pointer semantics to normal objects and allows them to be either set or not, without dynamic allocation.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

typedef boost::optional<std::vector<DWORD>> vec_opt;

vec_opt get_running_proc_list()
{
    DWORD proc_list[1024], size;

    if(!EnumProcesses(proc_list, sizeof(proc_list), &size))
    {
        return 0; 
    }

    vector<DWORD> _procs(proc_list, proc_list + size/sizeof(DWORD));
    return _procs;
}
```

And that's all you need to do, just change the return type. On the calling site:

```
vec_opt v = get_running_proc_list();
if(v){
  // successful and you can now go through the vector, accessing it with *v
  vector<DWORD>& the_v = *v;
  // use the_v ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return two logically distinct bits of information: First, "What are the list of processes?" and second, "Can I compute the list of processes?". I suggest you return those in two distinct variables:

```
// UNTESTED
bool get_running_proc_list(vector<DWORD>& result)
{
  DWORD proc_list[1024], size;

  if(!EnumProcesses(proc_list, sizeof(proc_list), &size))
  {
    return false; 
  }

  result = vector<DWORD>(proc_list, proc_list + size/sizeof(DWORD));
  return true;
}
```

But, I might try to save a couple `memcpy`'s:

```
// UNTESTED
bool get_running_proc_list(vector<DWORD>& result)
{
  result.clear();
  result.resize(1024);

  DWORD size;
  if(!EnumProcesses(&result[0], result.size()*sizeof(DWORD), &size))
  {
    result.clear();
    return false; 
  }
  result.resize(size/sizeof(DWORD));

  return true;
}
```